# How to insert values from jtable to database in netbeans

Tags: sql, netbeans, jtable

I could able to retrieve data from database but to insert data through jtable am unable to do it.Can anyone provide me suggestions to improve my coding skills in netbeans with database(sql).

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

```
sql1 = "INSERT INTO tblename (sample1,sample2,sample3,sample4) VALUES";

for (int i = 0; i < jTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
    String value1 = jTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
    String value2 = jTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
    String value3 = jTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
    String value4 = jTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
    sql2 = sql2 + "('"+value1+"', '"+value2+"', '"+value3+"', '"+value4+"'),";
}

sql2 = sql2.substring(0, sql2.length() - 1) + ";";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1 + sql2);
pst.execute();
```